# Extracting data to table for two rasters with identical polygons (different values) using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I have a raster image of watershed catchments where the raster value is the catchment ID. Using this raster and the "Zonal Statistics", I created a separate raster of land use where the raster value is land use. In each raster, there are identically shaped catchments. How do I generate a table of catchment and land use based on these images? I have ArcGIS Pro, it's just not clear what tool I would use.

Catchment---Land Use
020506.........4
95138..........12
etc.

[image: Above : Catchments, Below : Land Use]

Comment: Your title mentions "polygons" but rasters only have "cells". Are you asking how to make polygons from unique combinations of cells? If so, you could mask the two sources together, then generate polygons from the unique resulting values.

Comment: The top image is the catchment raster. There are "polygons" made from the pixels having the same catchment ID. I know I can convert the rasters to polygons based on pixel values - I just don't know how to make a table from two separate images / polygon sets

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS, I used Features to Points to create catchment points, then Extract Values to Points to add land use to the catchment data. The point data was exported to a csv.